# OR for two different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select specific rows from an Oracle DB.
The table has the following structure:

| Order | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2018 | 10 |
| 2 | 01.01.2018 | 15 |

I would like to extract all rows where

- Status = < 85 or
- the order date is in this week

Unfortunately, column Status is declared as a text column.

How would you build a SQL to extract these specific rows?

Comment: What is the data type of the "Date" column? (By the way, do you really have a column with that name? `DATE` is a reserved keyword, you can't create a column with that name unless you double-quote it, which is a bad practice anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I don't know what you mean by "this week".  Perhaps:

```
where status <= '85' or
      orderdate >= trunc(sysdate, 'IW')
```

This does a *string* comparison on the status, so `'9'` would not be matched, and uses the ISO definition of week for the current week.

If you want a numeric comparison for status, then:

```
where to_number(status) <= 85 or
      orderdate >= trunc(sysdate, 'IW')
```

Comment: This week = current week

Comment: @joshua - "current" is easy to understand, but what do you mean by week? Does the week begin on Monday (as in Europe), or on Sunday (as in the U.S.), or on Saturday (as in many Muslim countries) or ... ?

Comment: Yes, it means Mo-So (Europe)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the CAST function like

```
select* from yourtable where cast(Status as INT) <=85 AND 
to_char(to_date(date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')=to_char(to_date(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')
```